# Deploy gitlab artifact to microsoft azure web app using azure cli

Tags: azure, gitlab, gitlab-ci, azure-cli

Is it possible to deploy artifacts generated by GitLab with azure cli.

```
# Deploy sample code to "staging" slot from GitHub.
az webapp deployment source config --name $webappname --resource-group myResourceGroup \
--slot staging --repo-url $gitrepo --branch master --manual-integration
```

similar to this but only artifacts not the whole repository

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now, Azure Cli 2.0 supports to deploy webapp from Git or or Mercurial repositories. Currently, Gitlab is not supported.

> Group
>       az webapp deployment source: Manage source control systems.
>
> Commands:
>       config          : Associate to Git or Mercurial repositories.

You could deploy your webapp using manual steps. Please refer to this [link:Setting up continuous deployment using manual steps](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Continuous-deployment#setting-up-continuous-deployment-using-manual-steps).

Comment: Well i just need to copy the artifacts i am going to use ftp  but maybe you should consider adding support for gitlab :)

Comment: @DživoJelić You give feedback in this [link](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues).